# How can I extend a storm door frame that was cut short?

Tags: wood, security, frame, storm-door

The frame (z bar) was cut a little too short. I had my friend install the door for me and he cut it exactly to 80 1/8" on both sides. Is there something I can put here like a flexible piece of metal or something?
[image: Text]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Where's the scrap of Z-bar that was cut off? That seems like the obvious solution.

Comment: Yes. But how can I reattach the pieces? I've never worked with door frames before. Don't want my friend to touch this any further.

Comment: A drill bit and a screw? The same way the rest of it is attached.

Comment: drill holes for screws in the "scrap".

Comment: Worked perfectly after filing down the scrap pieces a bit. Thanks.